# What does "little use for sth" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[source](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/11/19/us/living-in-california.html)

> “There is no reason for these massive, deadly and costly forest fires
>   in California except that forest management is so poor,” Trump wrote,
>   finding **little use for** empathy or truth.

Who "finding little use for..."? Trump? Trump's tweet message? the Author?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally "has little use for/of" means that someone doesn't often need to use something.

> The tallest man in the world finds little use for a ladder.

Sometimes the expression might be used as an ironic understatement (*litotes*). Here it means "doesn't use at all"

> A fish has little use for a bicycle!

The participle phrase has the same subject as the main clause. Trump is finding little use for empathy.

So here it means Trump was not using "empathy" or "truth" when he wrote his tweet. So it means that the tweet by Trump was a cruel lie.

Answer (score 0):

According to Collins dictionary, [use](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/use) as in definition 2:

> 2. singular noun
>
> If you have a use for something, you need it or can find something to do with it.
>
> *You will no longer have a use for the magazines*. [+ for]
>
> *They both loved the fabric, but couldn't find a use for it*. [+ for]

So, Trump wrote that, while finding little use for empathy or truth.